# How can I remove a file from a Docker image that shows permissions only as question marks

Tags: linux

I have issue removing files on a Docker image. I am trying to remove the file `db.opt` but getting a message that this file doesn't exist and I see its permission as question marks. How can I force remove that file?

```
[root@0c68ac3b27ec mod_hpcdb]# ll
total 4

-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 65 May 2 07:28 db.opt

[root@0c68ac3b27ec mod_hpcdb]# rm -rf db.opt
[root@0c68ac3b27ec mod_hpcdb]# ll

ls: cannot access db.opt: No such file or directory

total 0 ?????????? ? ? ? ? ? db.opt
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically if there are question marls like that for permissions and ownership, that means that the permissions are above your current user’s default permissions. Meaning you should use `sudo` like this to force removal of the file via super user access:

```
sudo rm -rf db.opt
```

But in this case it seems like you are already logged in as root. So I would guess that `db.opt` is connected to some running process. Possibly MySQL? As explained [in this article here](http://code2care.org/2015/mysql-6-error-on-delete-of-databasedb.opt-errcode-13-permission-denied/):

> If you get this error message when you are tying to drop a MySQL database say *my_database* then the reason for this is **File Permissions** (Error code 13).
>
> Whenever we crate a database, a directory is created under `mysql/var/` ( XAMPP : `XAMPP/xamppfiles/mysql/var/`) with the same name as that of your database, this directory contains a file called `db.opt` which contains metadata related to the database.

So the issue is not really deleting `db.opt` as much as permissions for the parent directory that is somehow preventing MySQL from deleting it’s own table.

I would recommend stoping the MySQL service checking the ownership and permissions of the parent directory and getting them to match what MySQL requires and needs. If not, then just run a `chmod 777` on the parent directory, restart MySQL and then run the `DROP DATABASE <database_name>` on the database you wish to drop and all should be good again.

I personally would also recommend you reinstall MySQL again to ensure that permissions are fixed. But knowing how Docker continuers work that *might* mean destroying and rebuilding the Docker image so hey… Your choice.

Comment: as you see i am already root, thus sudo is not needed

Comment: @isb Fair enough. Look at my edit for more details.